# WordPress 3.3.1 single post template

Tags: templates

Does anybody have any idea why on single posts there are no template dropdowns for template selections in WP 3.3.1? I did not find that either in the page administrative area.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For page templates, click on screen options in the top right corner and check the Page Attributes box. If your theme has no page templates to choose from then the template drop down will not be shown.

Posts and other post types do not use or support page templates and never have. Only pages support them out of the box. You can install plugins however that let you have custom post templates. There is also the post formats feature.